# XML parser + Indexing data

Tags: java, lucene, xml-parsing, apache-tika, apache-commons-digester

I need to index some xml documents with Lucene, but before that, i need to parse those XML and extract some info inside their tags.

The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tt xml:lang="es" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2006/04/ttaf1"  xmlns:tts="http://www.w3.org/2006/04/ttaf1#styling">
  <head>
        <styling>
            <style id="bl" tts:fontWeight="bold" tts:color="#FFFFFF" tts:fontSize="15" tts:fontFamily="sansSerif"/>
       </styling>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div xml:lang="es">
            <p begin="00:00.50" end="00:04.02" style="bl">Info</p>
            <p begin="00:04.32" end="00:07.68" style="bl">Different words,<br />and phrases to index</p>
            <p begin="00:11.76" end="00:16.04" style="bl">Text</p>
            <p begin="00:18.52" end="00:22.88" style="bl">More and<br />more text</p>
   </div>
  </body>
</tt>
```

I need to extract only the timestamps inside the tags begin and end, and then index the text inside the p tags. The goal is to query the text indexed and know in which timestamp gap are each hit.

For example, if i query the word "Text" the output should say something like: "2 hits, 00:11.76-00:16.04, 00:18.52-00:22.88"

I started indexing the entire XML with Lucene. Now i want to parse the file, but im not sure what is the best approximation to solve this problem.

Any help or advice is welcome :)
Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the [SAX library](http://www.saxproject.org/quickstart.html) (i.e., a subclass of org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler ) to parse XML files, extracted the desired information from each XML document into my own Document class, and then indexed that Document instance. (The indirection was due to having multiple document formats that had to be parsed separately, but indexed in the same index.) In your case, if the contents of each of your <body> elements represents a logical document, you can store the date information as payloads associated with specific tokens. Parse the XML to the <p> level, enumerate the paragraph instances, and for each instance, add a new Field instance with the same name, where the value is the text, and the payload is the date information, suitably represented. (Payloads are binary, so, for example, you could store the two long values corresponding to the start and end times.) When you add multiple field instances with the same name to a document, they get indexed as the same field, but you can assign different payloads to each instance, you can adjust the position of the start of the text, etc.

If you don't need the contents of each  element as a single document, you can treat each <p> as a separate document, and then set the payload on that. Alternatively, you can store dates as a separate field.

Comment: I studied a little some parsers libraries and i think im going to use SAX, since i need to parse all the <p> tags but each of those tags have different values in their attributes. I'll be back if i find problems :D

Answer (score 3):

I can highly recommend storing all your XML in an [eXist](http://exist-db.org/) database, which has [Lucene built-in](http://exist.sourceforge.net/lucene.html). I've been using this combination for a few months now and it solves a lot of search and retrieval problems quite easily.

Comment: I've been looking the eXist database, and seems to be a very good tool, but what i need to do right now doesnt fit at all in this database. Anyway, thanx for the info :D